# How do i generate a string consisting of m number of rows and n number of cols, using random function

Tags: python, string, random, import

Write a function named `place_random_bricks(m, n, colours)` that randomly places bricks row-wise (completes the current row placement before moving to the next row) on the baseplate.

It must have three parameters:

- `m` - the number of rows on the base-plate,
- `n` - the number of columns on the base-plate, and
- `colours` - a random string constructed over “G, R, B, Y, C”
  (G-Green, R-Red, Blue-B, Y-Yellow, C-Cyan).

This function should return a string of length `m * n`, where a character at any position `i` represents the colour of a brick placed on the baseplate
`(0 ≤ i < (m x n), i ∈ “colours′′);` a value “G” (Green colour) represents no brick was placed.

All colours have an equal probability of being selected.

```
import random
import colorama
import string

def place_random_bricks(m, n, colours):
    v_string=['G', 'R', 'B', 'Y', 'C']
    for i in range(m * n):
        colours = string.ascii_uppercase
        a = print(''.join(random.choices(colours)))
```

I am expecting a random number of RYBCG.

Comment: Unclear. `return ''.join(random.choices("GRBYC", k = m * n))`??

Comment: Why are you using `string.ascii_uppercase`?  Why are you overwriting the colors parameter you were given?  Why do you have `v_string` and never use it?  You're building a 1D list, not a 2D array.

Comment: You will need two loops: one over rows (`for y in range(m):`), and one over columns (`for x in range(n):`, in which you choose a color at random (`c = random.choice(colours)`).  You build up each row, then add the row to your matrix.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please elaborate please??. That will be really helpfull. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using numpy to generate random 2d arrays since. and the using a lookup string to convert those numbers to the list of random colours you want it to be converted to.

```py
import numpy as np
def place_random_bricks(m,n, colors):
    ar = np.random.randint(0,len(colors),(m,n))
    return '\n'.join([''.join([colors[j] for j in i]) for i in ar])

print(place_random_bricks(4,5,['G','R','B','Y','C']))
```

Comment: The question is asking me not to print the value just return the value and can it be done with out using the numpy and just using the random function?

Comment: The function does in fact return the value, I'm simply printing it to demonstrate the function working. Yes, it can be done without numpy.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you wouldn't have to return an m*n matrix, but it clearly says it wants one string.

```
import random

def place_random_bricks(m, n, colours):
    row = [random.choice(colours) for _ in range(m*n)]
    return ''.join(row)

print(place_random_bricks(5,5,'GRBYC'))
```

Output:

```
GGYGYBBCBGYCCGYGCRRRCBGCB
```